# Images not rendering in Django in pages with forms

Tags: python, django, image, caching, browser-cache

Forewarning, I am very new to Django and Python in general. So my images render perfectly with all my other urls. But lets say I have a blog and when I edit a blog post, the url would be as follows:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/14/edit/

Or for adding a comment:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/3/comment/

And the images would not render for those urls. The pattern seems kind of obvious but I still don't know what the issue is. Now, if I was just creating a new post, with the url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/new/

The images render fine. Is this a caching issue or what? I've tried clearing my cache and it will work for a little bit and then fail to render later. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a fiddle/public git repo of urls.py , views.py, forms.py and the HTML you are rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hardcoding your static URLs which is breaking when the URL of the page changes since they're relative.

```
../../static/images/logo.png
```

Django provides a `{% static %}` tag for generating these URLs. Replace with:

```
{% static 'images/logo.png' %}
```

At `/post/new/`, your relative static URL resolves to `/static/images/logo.png`, but on your edit pages, it's resolving to `/post/static/images/logo.png`.